# NKOColorPickerView: Get updated color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using a library called NKOColorPickerView (https://github.com/FWCarlos/NKO-Color-Picker-View-iOS)

The the library gives the following method to identify If the color has been changed from palette.

```
NKOColorPickerDidChangeColorBlock colorDidChangeBlock = ^(UIColor *color){
    //Your code handling a color change in the picker view.
};
```

I was wondering If it is possible to get the color which is currently selected. I have an imageView on my storyboard and I would like to change the background color of the storyboard to the selected color in the palette.

I tried the following code, but It doesn't work. Please help me. I am newbie.

> [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor
>   NKOColorPickerDidChangeColorBlock:colorDidChangeBlock]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work do the trick:

```
[imageView setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, you are supposed to add a block callback to the `didChangeColorBlock` property, and handle color change from it.

```
__weak __block __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

colorPicker.didChangeColorBlock = ^(UIColor *color){
    [weakSelf.imageView setBackgroundColor:color];
};
```

Time to brush up your knowledge about blocks.

Comment: The `__block` modifier is not needed with ARC because `weakSelf` is not modified in the block. (In the ancient pre-ARC times, `__block`  served similar purposes as `weak` does now.)